# molden install gives fatal compilation error

Tags: software-installation, make

I'm trying to install molden5.7. I've followed the steps on [this guide](https://mklammler.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/update-installing-molden-on-64bit-debian-based-gnulinux-systems/), just changing the version. I tried it once before and it worked, but this time when I get to the `make` step, I get

```
xwin.c:12:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
<builtin>: recipe for target 'xwin.o' failed
make: *** [xwin.o] Error 1
```

I've tried to install the `X11` libs the guide requested, but I get an

```
E: unable to locate package libX11-6
E: unable to locate package libX11-dev
```

Both this comp and the one I succeeded with are on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

Comment: The packages are called `libx11-dev` and `libx11-6` (lower case `x`) iirc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made a typing mistake, the actual package you want is called `libx11-dev` (with lowercase **x**). So the command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install libx11-6
```

If you search [libX11-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libX11-dev&searchon=names) on [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com), it will return `libx11-dev` and not `libX11-dev` (notice the **X**). Make sure you have type the package correctly before attempting any install command.

Comment: Aha! That guide does use capital X <-<